# How to setup quartz to trigger job with a schedule for each day of week?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I would like to know if is possible create a setup to fire a same job with diferent dates.

for instance, Sunday the time to fire a job is 13:00, Monday is 14:00 ... Saturday: 19:00

Can I create a list of triggers? If yes, How can I set this list on Scheduler object?

Comment: I believe you can, just show some of your tries, here is few documentation so seems that you can:  http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.2.x/tutorials/crontrigger You could do it like this.. create different jobs for each day time OR you can create a single job that runs every hour and inside the task you compare the hour, I'd rather suggest to create different jobs.

Comment: I would just trigger it every hour then put logic inside your trigger to only continue if it is monday and it is between 14:00-14:30. If you want to play with it I would use http://www.cronmaker.com/

Comment: unfortunately this does not solve my problem, I can have different schedules to execute the job for each day of the week.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? Perfectly valid question

Answer (score 1):

I found what I was looking for [here](http://www.onlinetechvision.com/?p=104)

Quartz 2.0 allows create a trigger list and link with a single job.